# How does singular homology work?: $H_1(S^1)$.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

This is a fundamental inquiry into the nature of singular homology. Let $\gamma$ and $\sigma$ be the following singular 1-chains on the circle:
$$\gamma(t)=2\pi t,~~~~~\sigma(t)=4\pi t,$$
Now, based on geometric intuition, the following conjecture should be obvious:

> **Conjecture:** There exists some 2-chain $\eta$ whose boundary is $2\gamma-\sigma$.

What is $\eta$? Can I answer this question without passing to other forms of homology (i.e. simplicial, cellular, etc.)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are parametrizing $S^1$ as $\mathbb{R}/2\pi\mathbb{Z}$.  To find such an $\eta$, consider the map $f:\partial\Delta^2\to S^1$ whose zeroth edge is $\gamma$, first edge is $\sigma$, and second edge is $\gamma$ (here I am using the standard orientation for boundary faces of a simplex, so if you orient them to all be going around counterclockwise, the $\sigma$ edge is "backwards").  Then $f$ is nullhomotopic (its winding number is easily seen to be zero; you can also explicitly write down a nullhomotopy without too much trouble), so it extends to a map $\eta:\Delta^2\to S^1$.  By construction, the boundary of the chain $\eta$ is $2\gamma-\sigma$.